# Найдите кота(,) большего, чем кот под именем Леонард, и, его найдя, определите, как его, кота этого, зовут

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые? Я думаю, что в первом нужны, а во втором — нет.

> Найдите кота(,) большего, чем кот под именем Леонард, и, его найдя, определите, как его, кота этого, зовут.

> Найдите кота(,) большего, чем кот под именем Леонард.